# how upload object in oracle database by java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle9i

I want to upload **multiple objects** to my oracle database **using java**.

My objects included { DOC, DOCX , PPT , PPTX , PDF  } files.

How I can upload my objects in oracle database and retrieve it from database.

also I am interested to know more about "How can I batch insert list of objects in Oracle database from Java?" but I think this question answered before. If you have any new or interesting resource please share with me please ...

Comment: Are you using some kind of ORM, Oracle Objects or you want to persist instances in the database?

Comment: Did you want to ask, "_How can I batch insert list of objects in Oracle database from Java?_"

Comment: I add some note to my question,please read it again

Answer (score 3):

Insert into db:

```
int primaryKeyId = getNextPrimaryKeyId();
PreparedStatement stmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(" insert into docTable values (?, ?, empty_blob()) ");
stmt1.setInt(1, primaryKeyId );
stmt1.setString(2, getDocumentTitle());
stmt1.executeUpdate();

PreparedStatement stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(" select doc from docTable where id = ? for update ");
stmt2.setInt(1, primaryKeyId);
stmt2.execute();

OracleResultSet rset = (OracleResultSet)stmt2.getResultSet();
if (rset.next()) {
  BLOB document = rset.getBLOB("doc");
  document.trim(0);
  OutputStream os = document.getBinaryOutputStream();
  os.write(getDocumentToBeWrittenToDb());
  os.flush;
  os.close;
}
```

Read from db:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(" select title, doc from docTable where id = ?");
stmt.setInt(1, primaryKeyId);
stmt.execute();

BLOB document;
OracleResultSet rset = (OracleResultSet)stmt.getResultSet();

if (rset.next())
{
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
  InputStream is = null;
  try
  {
    BLOB document = rset.getBLOB("document");
    String title = rset.getString("title");
    is = document.getBinaryStream();
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
    int len;
    while ((len = is.read(data)) != -1)
    {
      baos.write(data, 0, len);
    }
  } finally
  {
    if (null != baos) baos.close();
    if (null != is) is.close();
  }

  return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: I dont have oracleResultSet, where I can find this package?

Answer (score 0):

If you are

1. running on Linux and  the database
2. version is 11gR2 and  you have
3. created a dbfs in it and  you have
4. mounted it using the dbfs_client

you can access the filesystem as a regular networked filesystem. Doing so is the easiest way to store non structured data in the database using regular filesystem io. The dbfs_client translated the calls using fuse. If needed you can create the relations to other data later.

Ronald.

Comment: I am running on Windows xp :(

Comment: In that case you might be able to re-mount the fs using smb. You still need the dbfs to be mounted on some Linux app/file server that exports it to your Windows machine.